# Evaluation of this Double integration using polar co-ordinates?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, jacobian

I'm trying to evaluate the double integral

$$\int_{0}^{5/\sqrt{2}}\int_{y}^{\sqrt{25-y^2}}xy~dx~dy$$

but using Cartesian coordinates requires the idea of trigonometric substitution and the limits aren't very nice either. So, my question is, how can I change this integral into another one in polar coordinates that would make the evaluation easier? it will be even more helpful .if you can find the volume

Comment: What do you get when you just take the first integral?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Could you show us some of what you've tried?  [As noted on meta, this site does not support homework questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26620/is-the-daily-question-limit-always-useful-right?noredirect=1#comment105412_26620).  To ask well-received questions, we recommend you read [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)

Comment: Step 0: Make a sketch of the region you integrate over. Then the conversion into polar coordinates should be easy to see.

Comment: i have tried some thing i will post it soon -@Simply Beautiful Art

Comment: Why trigonometric substitiution? As far as I can see, evaluating this integral directly involves only integration of polynomial functions. (Specifically the square root in the inner integral's upper limit is squared since $\int xy~dx = \frac {x^2y}{2} + C$)

Comment: This is very straightforward and the answer is ${625 \over 16}$.  Why not just perform the trivial integrals?  Do you *have* to use polar coordinates?  Why oh why??